# Invert Crop from (Cut hole into) Image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, crop

Everywhere I look online, I see people posting on how to successfully crop an image. However, I want to 'crop'/ clear a hole out of an image. I want to keep the original image, but crop out a rectangle

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I have "cropped" out the kittens face.  I maintained the original image, but removed only part of it. I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: Overlay a white rectangle on top of the original image.

Comment: i dont want it to be a white rectangle, i want to remove the pixels in that section.

Comment: Show a picture of what you want, because your picture is of a white rectangle on top of the original image.

Comment: that is what I want. I want to have an original picture and using System.Drawing.Rectangle, "extract" or "Crop" out a defined section, leaving the original image.

Comment: So you want to make that rectangle transparent? or want to crop a copy ?

Comment: I want to have an original image, then through code, I want to define a rectangle inside of that image, and remove its pixels that are within the bounds of the rectangle. I want to "cut" out an image from within another.  Everywhere I look only, they are cutting the image, but giving you the new cut out image, where i do not care for the cropped image, I just want to remove the pixels where I have defined

Comment: So what is wrong with the original suggestion of overlaying a white rectangle. You cannot simply "remove" pixels.

Comment: Would you please answer my question: _you want to make that rectangle transparent?_

Comment: Yes thank you TaW, I didn't see your original request. Thank you for taking the time to post an answer!

Comment: Hi; I think I misspoke in my answer and if you just want to erase to transparency you can do so as in @Medinoc's answer. Please change his answer to be the accepted one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace the original pixel colors with transparency you run into a small problem: You **can't draw or fill with transparency** in GDI+.

But **you can** use `Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)`.

To do that you **restrict** the region where the `Graphics` object will draw. Here we can use the simple cropping rectangle but you can clear more complex shapes using a `GraphicsPath`..

Example using a bitmap `bmp`:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(222,222,55,55);
    g.SetClip(crop);
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
}
bmp.Save(somefilename, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, thats exactly what i needed

Comment: Yes you can add semitransparent pixels but you can't take a given alpha of any pixel down to 0 or any lower value. so you are drawing with transparency but you can't draw the transparency itself.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your `Graphics` object's `CompositingMode` property to `CompositingMode.SourceCopy` will allow your drawing operations to replace the alpha value instead of proportionally opacifying it:

```cs
        public static void TestDrawTransparent()
        {
            //This code will, successfully, draw something transparent overwriting an opaque area.
            //More precisely, it creates a 100*100 fully-opaque red square with a 50*50 semi-transparent center.
            using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            {
                using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                using(Brush opaqueRedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)))
                using(Brush semiRedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0)))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                    Rectangle bigRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
                    Rectangle smallRect = new Rectangle(25, 25, 50, 50);
                    g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    g.FillRectangle(opaqueRedBrush, bigRect);
                    g.FillRectangle(semiRedBrush, smallRect);
                }
                bmp.Save(@"C:\FilePath\TestDrawTransparent.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
```

In this code, I first draw a fully-opaque red square, then a semi-transparent red square "over" it. The result is a semi-transparent "hole" in the square:

[image: Red square with semi-transparent center]
And on a black background:
[image: The square with semi-transparent hole, on a black background]

A zero-opacity brush works just as well, leaving a clear hole through the image (I checked).
With that in mind, you should be able to crop any shapes you want, simply by filling them with a zero-opacity brush.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. - It should be noted though, that this, while good enough for a 100% eraser,  will still not draw or fill transparency, as it __replaces__ both alpha and all color channels. For that a (much) more involved process is needed..

Comment: @TaW ah, you mean if you want to change *only* the alpha channel? There may be a way to do it for a rectangle by copying said rectangle to a new 24-bit image, then using an overload of `DrawImage` that accepts an `ImageAttributes` to pass a color matrix that multiplies the alpha value of what you draw... Need to test.

Comment: SourceCopy will overwrite all channels and not combine anything, so it will not allow one to gradually change the alpha channel like an eraser with say 105 opacity..

Comment: Matrix: Interesting idea. - I prefer to do it with lockbits and can then combine the temp bitmap with the tgt bitmap pixels in any way. Very flexible! -  I realized a class that implements all photoshop blendmodes and then some.. .